# Preprocessor directive #define specific to my machine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, macros, projects-and-solutions, preprocessor-directive

I have a Visual Studio 2013 project, using the VC++ 2010 Platform Toolkit.

I know I could add a #define preprocessor directive by means of

PROJECT > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > 
Preprocessor definitions.

However that would check-out the .vcxproj and .filters files, which I could accidentally check-in and affect everyone else's environment.

I want to add that #define specifically only to my machine. I searched the Internet for some info on the format of the .user project user options file, but documentation is practically nonexistent.

Is there a way I could do that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx#bkmkPropertySheets) link helps you to solve your problem.
Please take note of below important notes in the shared link

> A .props file by default does not participate in source control
>   because it isn’t created as a project item. You can manually add the
>   file as a solution item if you want to include it in source control.

Comment: For VC++ 2010, the below blog has all needed details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/14/a-guide-to-vcxproj-and-props-file-structure.aspx